# Possibility of using loops instead of traps

Tags: finite-automata, loops

Draw DFA for the language of all strings starting with $a$ and ending with $b$.
Now what I have done is

[image]

Here I used q3 as a trap.
But could I do this instead?

[image]

I have not used trap in the 2nd solution and used a self loop instead.

Comment: The first automaton rejects $bab$, the second one accepts it.

Comment: you self loop allows for bab to pass

Comment: Got it.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your first DFA is minimal. To see this, for each pair of states $q_i \neq q_j$ we need to come up with a word $w$ such that $\delta(q_i,w) \in F$ and $\delta(q_j,w) \notin F$, or vice versa, where $F$ is the set of accepting states.

Here is such a list of words:

- $q_0,q_1$: $\delta(q_0,b) \notin F$ and $\delta(q_1,b) \in F$.
- $q_0,q_2$: $\delta(q_0,\epsilon) \notin F$ and $\delta(q_2,\epsilon) \in F$.
- $q_0,q_3$: $\delta(q_0,ab) \in F$ and $\delta(q_3,ab) \notin F$.
- $q_1,q_2$: $\delta(q_1,\epsilon) \notin F$ and $\delta(q_2,\epsilon) \in F$.
- $q_1,q_3$: $\delta(q_1,b) \in F$ and $\delta(q_3,b) \notin F$.
- $q_2,q_3$: $\delta(q_2,\epsilon) \in F$ and $\delta(q_3,\epsilon) \notin F$.